# Stripe Connect Express - Callback URI for Localhost Doesn't Seem to Work

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to set up a platform that uses Stripe, and since I need marketplace type of setup I'm using Connect, which does payments and payouts.

I'm testing on local and the redirect URLs I've tried don't seem to work. After registering with Stripe, I'm still taken to their default redirect URI, which says:

> Congrats, you're almost done setting up your application! After
>   connecting with Stripe, your users will be redirected to a page of
>   your choosing (this is just the default). Make sure to change the test
>   redirect URI under your application settings to something that makes
>   sense on your own server (or localhost).

However, I have tried all of these as redirect URIs in my Stripe Connect Dashboard, under the 'testing' option:

http://localhost:8000/test-stripe/connect/default/oauth/test

http://localhost:8000/test-stripe/oauth/callback

http://localhost:8000/test-stripe/

These are supposed to be the URI that Stripe redirects back to on my site, with an added parameter at the end.

Am I missing something? I find their documentation labyrinthine, as you have to click on link after link to get one part of their solution working, and then see if you can find your way back to where you left off. Maybe I missed something along the way.

The test link to Stripe:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<h2 style="margin-top:50px;">Testing Stripe...</h2>
{% csrf_token %}
<a id="test-stripe" href="https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=https://stripe.com/connect/default/oauth/test&client_id=ca_FXp5f7CsYa0ddYm2Jri4zflYuMIPp5wT">stripe</a>
<script>
    var token = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    var stripeLink = document.getElementById("test-stripe");
    stripeLink.href = stripeLink.href + "&state="+token;
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: What does your call to create the Connect request/account look like currently?

Comment: Hi @taintedzodiac, I've added the link to Stripe in the post above.

Comment: And @taintedzodiac I suspect there could be an issue with my token, but not sure yet what. I'm using these docs: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#integrating-oauth
Specifically, on that page it says:
To prevent CSRF attacks, add the state parameter with the value set to a unique token. Stripe includes this state value in the redirect URL that sends the user back to your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I still had Stripe.com's `redirect_uri` parameter in the URL - oops.